# How would I put a small image in the content of a span for a button

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a button that has a small cat slide over to the right on hover using CSS character entities. How would I add a PNG in place of the character entity but also contain it in similar dimensions?

Something like this. I tried setting height and width queries to the span section but that didn't work. The image ends up just covering the button text and overflowing into the section even with `overflow: hidden;`. Does it need its own container?

```
     <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>I am a button</span></button>
```

```
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-color: #f4511e;
      border: none;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      transition: all 0.5s;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 2px;
     }
  
    .button span {
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     transition: 0.5s;
    }
  
    .button span:after {
        content: url("http.tempimage);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
     }
    
    .button:hover span {
    padding-right: 25px;
    }
  
    .button:hover span:after {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
    }
```